# Stream.dropWhile() doesn't return correct value in two different values

Tags: java, java-stream, java-9

I am trying to learn new features in Java-9 I come to know about the dropWhile method of Stream but it is returning different values in two different scenarios.
Here is my code

```
package src.module;

import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s[] = new String[3];
        s[0] = "Hello";
        s[1] = "";
        s[2] = "World";
        List<String> value = Stream.of(s).dropWhile(a -> a.isEmpty()).collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(value);

        List<String> values = Stream.of("a", "b", "c", "", "e", "f").dropWhile(d -> !d.isEmpty())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(values);

    }
}
```

Here is the answer what I am getting

```
[Hello, , World]
[, e, f]
```

What I think in first condition it should print [,World].
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what my doubt is in the first condition it then returns the Hello only and the left two value should be dropped. Isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`dropWhile` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#dropWhile(java.util.function.Predicate)), introduced in Java 9, will remove the longest starting set of elements that match the predicate.

> Returns, if this stream is ordered, a stream consisting of the remaining elements of this stream after dropping the longest prefix of elements that match the given predicate.

Because your condition is that the item is empty, and the first item is not empty, nothing is removed, leaving `["Hello", "", "World"]` intact.

At the end, when you call `dropWhile` with the opposite condition, is not empty, the first 3 items match and are removed, leaving `["", "e", "f"]`, which are the remaining items.

This is the expected behavior.

Comment: what my doubt is in the first condition it then returns the Hello only and the left two value should be dropped. Isn't it?

Comment: @HarshKumrawat nothing should be dropped, since the "longest prefix of elements that match the given predicate" is empty.

Answer (score 3):

Your first condition is saying to drop items until a non-empty item is found The second condition says to drop items until an empty item is found. Add a '!' to your first condition to get your predicted result.

Comment: what my doubt is in the first condition it then returns the Hello only and the left two value should be dropped. Isn't it?

Comment: The 'dropWhile' runs as long as the provided condition is true. It stops when the condition is false. In the first loop, the condition is false from the start. In the second loop, it is true for 2 elements of the stream.

Comment: @HarshKumrawat What he's saying is, you put `a.isEmpty()` when you wanted `!a.isEmpty()`. That's why the output isn't what you expected.

Answer (score 2):

The Javadoc of [dropWhile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#dropWhile-java.util.function.Predicate-) states:

> Returns, if this stream is ordered, a stream consisting of the remaining elements of this stream after dropping the longest prefix of elements that match the given predicate.

In the first snippet, the first element of the `Stream` doesn't satisfy `a -> a.isEmpty()`, so no elements are dropped.

In the second snippet, the first 3 elements in the `Stream` satisfy `d -> !d.isEmpty()`, so these 3 elements are dropped, leaving `""`, `"e"` & `"f"`.

Comment: what my doubt is in the first condition it then returns the Hello only and the left two value should be dropped. Isn't it?

Comment: @HarshKumrawat Nothing should be dropped, since the "longest prefix of elements that match the given predicate" is empty.

Answer (score 2):

In order to better understand the algorithm, you can try to replace a `Stream` version:

```
List<String> value = Stream.of(s).dropWhile(String::isEmpty).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

with a classic `for` loop:

```
List<String> value = new ArrayList<>();
boolean dropping = true;

for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    String str = s[i];
    if (dropping) {
        if (str.isEmpty()) {
            continue;
        }
        dropping = false;
    }
    value.add(str);
}
```

Comment: As I am learning the stream feature so I only want to use Stream methods.Thanks for the answer

Comment: This is just a view from a different angle :) ... Keep learning!