# Question about java streams dropWhile example in Modern Java in Action

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm reading Modern Java in Action at the moment. In the streams section there's one thing that isn't clear to me.
We have list:

```
//public Dish(String name, boolean vegetarian, int calories, Type type)


List<Dish> specialMenu = Arrays.asList(
new Dish("seasonal fruit", true, 120, Dish.Type.OTHER),
new Dish("prawns", false, 300, Dish.Type.FISH),
new Dish("rice", true, 350, Dish.Type.OTHER),
new Dish("chicken", false, 400, Dish.Type.MEAT),
new Dish("french fries", true, 530, Dish.Type.OTHER));
```

And then we use dropWhile to find elemets greater than 320 calories.

```
List <Dish> slicedMenu2 = specialMenu.stream()
 .dropWhile(dish -> dish.getCalories() < 320)
 .collect(toList());
```

And it says that  (quote from book) - 
   "The dropWhile operation is the complement of takeWhile. It throws away the elements
at the start where the predicate is false. Once the predicate evaluates to true it
stops and returns all the remaining elements (...)"

In the way I think, that dropWhile  throws away elements while predicate is true, and stops when it evaluates to false, but book states opposite.
What I'm not getting here?

Comment: i did't use streams much but what i understood is that it is collecting those elements to slicedMenu2 which are greater than 320 in calories,, do you want me to open the book and explain?

Comment: Did you check this answer?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52613656/2553521

Comment: Yeah they got a bug in the book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#dropWhile(java.util.function.Predicate)):

> Returns, if this stream is ordered, a stream consisting of the remaining elements of this stream after dropping the longest prefix of elements that match the given predicate.

You understanding is correct, so there must be a mistake in the book.

Comment: Thank You. I checked book's forum and errata and didn't find anything about this, so I thought maybe I don't understand something.